# Is it possible to test whether two iterators point to the same object?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Say I'm making a function to copy a value:

```
template<class ItInput, class ItOutput>
void copy(ItInput i, ItOutput o) { *o = *i; }
```

and I would like to **avoid the assignment** if `i` and `o` point to the same object, since then the assignment is pointless.

Obviously, I can't say `if (i != o) { ... }`, both because `i` and `o` might be of different types and because they might point into different containers (and would thus be incomparable).  Less obviously, I can't use overloaded function templates either, because the iterators might belong to different containers even though they have the same type.

My initial solution to this was:

```
template<class ItInput, class ItOutput>
void copy(ItInput i, ItOutput o)
{
    if (&*o != static_cast<void const *>(&*i))
        *o = *i;
}
```

but I'm not sure if this works. What if `*o` or `*i` actually returns an object instead of a reference?

Is there a way to do this generally?

Comment: Oh I see... 'aite. Favoriting this :)

Comment: When you say '... if input and output are the same...', do you mean the same value, or iterators that point to the same location in a container?

Comment: @Rollie: The latter. It was a typo on my part since I'd changed the variable names (they were originally `input` and `output`); fixed now.

Comment: I agree w/chrad, your solution is fine.  Your concern about *o/*i returning an object has more significant implications in that the meat of the function `*o = *i;` won't work in that case as well, given that both are of the same type.

Comment: @Rollie: You're right... but the fact that they were of the same type was a typo, not intentional; please see my correction.

Comment: What category of iterator do you require for the iterators?  Can they actually be input and output iterators?  An input iterator is only single-pass, so you can't indirect it twice.  _Strictly_, only an input iterator may be a proxy iterator (an iterator whose `operator*` returns an object, not a reference). Forward, bidirectional, and random access iterators can't return a proxy. In practice, this is not always followed, because it's extremely useful to have a proxy iterator that provides random access (also, I don't know how you could implement `vector<bool>` efficiently without doing this)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Yes, they can actually be I/O iterators (or bidi or forward or random-access). I hadn't thought about the dereference-twice rule! And I had no idea only input iterators could be proxies. Great points, thanks.

Comment: Well, if `ItOutput` can be an output iterator, then there's no _general_ solution:  you can't read from an output range, you can only assign into it.  You could specialize for forward+ iterators, but I would recommend against that, due to the commonness of illicit forward+ proxy iterators (you could test the type of the indirection expression and see if that is a reference, but even that could yield false positives in corner cases).  I would make the assignment unconditionally.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Ah okay. If that's correct then that'd a great answer, if you'd like to post it. :)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis A random-access iterator can return a proxy for an indexing operation `a[n]`, which is only required to be convertible to `reference`. And the operational semantics for that are specified to be `*(a + n)`. I'm having a hard time figuring out what that means exactly for e.g. `*a--`.

Comment: @LucDanton:  The important rule is at §24.2.5[forward.iterators]/6 which mandates that for two forward iterators `a` and `b`, "if `a` and `b` are both dereferenceable, then `a == b` if and only if `*a` and `*b` are bound to the same object."  That requirement can only be satisfied if indirection yields a reference.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis does that mean I can't write a random-access iterator over all integers that uses no backing storage?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes:  That is correct.  I was quite surprised to learn this a few months ago.  In all but a very few corner cases (like the one discussed in this question), it won't cause problems though, so given the high value that a random access proxy iterator can provide, I'd argue that it's probably okay to do, despite the fact that the specification says you are not allowed to.

Comment: @James do you know if there is a DR for this? If not I may submit one. I really think the value provided for lifting that restriction is worth it.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes:  I don't see a DR for this specific issue, though I haven't been paying close attention to the mailings for the last two years or so (that will change Monday, though, when I make my return to C++ programming :-D).  There is some discussion of this issue in [LWG1211](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1211), wherein Howard Hinnant comments "I believe that the requirement that forward iterators have a dereference that returns an lvalue reference to cause unacceptable pessimization," and mentions the `vector<bool>` case.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes:  There was some discussion at BoostCon'12 that a new hierarchy of iterator concepts might be required, to correctly handle all of the differences in kinds of iterators, e.g. to correctly account for const iterators, move iterators, proxy iterators, and other categories.  It seems like many people are of the opinion that the current structure is insufficient to represent the full breadth of capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that this is really necessary:  if assignment is expensive, the type should define an assignment operator that performs the (relatively cheap) self assignment check to prevent doing unnecessary work.  But, it's an interesting question, with many pitfalls, so I'll take a stab at answering it.

If we are to assemble a general solution that works for input and output iterators, there are several pitfalls that we must watch out for:

- An input iterator is a single-pass iterator:  you can only perform indirection via the iterator once per element, so, we can't perform indirection via the iterator once to get the address of the pointed-to value and a second time to perform the copy.
- An input iterator may be a proxy iterator.  A proxy iterator is an iterator whose `operator*` returns an object, not a reference.  With a proxy iterator, the expression `&*it` is ill-formed, because `*it` is an rvalue (it's possible to overload the unary-`&`, but doing so is usually considered evil and horrible, and most types do not do this).
- An output iterator can only be used for output; you cannot perform indirection via it and use the result as an rvalue.  You can write to the "pointed to element" but you can't read from it.

So, if we're going to make your "optimization," we'll need to make it only for the case where both iterators are forward iterators (this includes bidirectional iterators and random access iterators:  they're forward iterators too).

Because we're nice, we also need to be mindful of the fact that, despite the fact that it violates the concept requirements, many proxy iterators misrepresent their category because it is very useful to have a proxy iterator that supports random access over a sequence of proxied objects.  (I'm not even sure how one could implement an efficient iterator for `std::vector<bool>` without doing this.)

We'll use the following Standard Library headers:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
```

We define a metafunction, `is_forward_iterator`, that tests whether a type is a "real" forward iterator (i.e., is not a proxy iterator):

```
template <typename T>
struct is_forward_iterator :
    std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        std::is_base_of<
            std::forward_iterator_tag,
            typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category
        >::value &&
        std::is_lvalue_reference<
            decltype(*std::declval<T>())
        >::value>
{ };
```

For brevity, we also define a metafunction, `can_compare`, that tests whether two types are both forward iterators:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct can_compare :
    std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        is_forward_iterator<T>::value &&
        is_forward_iterator<U>::value
    >
{ };
```

Then, we'll write two overloads of the `copy` function and use SFINAE to select the right overload based on the iterator types:  if both iterators are forward iterators, we'll include the check, otherwise we'll exclude the check and always perform the assignment:

```
template <typename InputIt, typename OutputIt>
auto copy(InputIt const in, OutputIt const out)
    -> typename std::enable_if<can_compare<InputIt, OutputIt>::value>::type
{
    if (static_cast<void const volatile*>(std::addressof(*in)) != 
        static_cast<void const volatile*>(std::addressof(*out)))
        *out = *in;
}

template <typename InputIt, typename OutputIt>
auto copy(InputIt const in, OutputIt const out)
    -> typename std::enable_if<!can_compare<InputIt, OutputIt>::value>::type
{
    *out = *in;
}
```

As easy as pie!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed comment, but I just found this answer after doing a bunch of research (including a post to comp.std.c++, which has an interesting case of a non-proxy iterator with a similar issue). Two forward iterators, even if of the same type, are not comparable if unless they have the same underlying sequence (24.2.5/2). So unless you know that two iterators are within a common range, it's UB to compare them, and I don't believe there is any way to test whether the iterators are in the same range, because the test in 24.2.1/6 relies on `==`.

Comment: @rici: To which part of this answer are you objecting?

Comment: ah, sorry. I misread can_compare (confusing it with its name). So your intention is to bypass `operator==` on the basis that the fact that two addresses compare equal is sufficient to demonstrate that the objects pointed to are essentially the same object, even if the objects are different types. That also strikes me as questionable, but it wasn't the question I originally had, so I withdraw my objection, and sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be a case where you may have to document some assumptions about the types you  expect in the function and be content with not being completely generic.

Like `operator*`, `operator&` could be overloaded to do all sorts of things. If you're guarding against `operator*`, then you should consider `operator&` and `operator!=`, etc.

I would say that a good prerequisite to enforce (either through comments in the code or a concept/static_assert) is that `operator*` returns a reference to the object pointed to by the iterator and that it doesn't (or shouldn't) perform a copy. In that case, your code as it stands seems fine.

Comment: Should I just ignore `std::iterator_traits<It>::reference` and `std::iterator_traits<It>::pointer` then? I mean, if I could dereferenced iterators as plain references and (and their addresses as pointers) then there was no point in having either of those typedef's defined in `iterator_traits`, right? `value_type` would've been sufficient.

Comment: @Mehrdad those are defined because they make using iterators with less trivial functions a lot easier.  Sometimes you need to use the actual type that the iterator points to, and then you'll need to use those typedefs.

Comment: *"Sometimes you need to use the actual type that the iterator points to"* If I can treat iterators as pointers, then isn't that just `value_type`? Why would I need `pointer` or `reference` then?

Comment: @Mehrdad You cannot treat iterators as pointers. The iterator concepts do not guarantee that `&*it` is correct (or what its type should be if it is), so you have to follow the advice here and roll out your own concept to explain that the template expects `&*it != &*it` to work. This gives a chance to would-be users to e.g. provide or fix an overloaded `operator&` to the `reference` type if need be.

Comment: "I would say that a good assumption is that `operator*` returns a reference to the object pointed to by the iterator" -- Except it's not, since input iterators are allowed to dereference to anything "convertible to `T`" (§24.2.3/2).

Comment: @LucDanton: Ah, I see. So your answer is basically "it isn't possible unless you impose additional restrictions"? (I don't mind answers that say something is impossible!)

Comment: @Xeo I wasn't implying that it was a guarantee, but a good assumption to add as a comment or enforce with concepts. I guess that wasn't clear.

Comment: @Mehrdad Well, it *is* possible since the template will still be usable with iterators that conform to the expectations. But it's nicer to users and a good exercise in concepts to document.

Comment: I think a better assumption would be that `&*it` 'does the right thing' (and is at least comparable) even if `IteratorTraits::reference` is not a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as is, is definitly *not* okay, or atleast not okay for all iterator categories.

Input iterators and output iterators are not required to be dereferenceable after the first time (they're expected to be single-pass) and input iterators are allowed to dereference to anything "convertible to `T`" (§24.2.3/2).

So, if you want to handle all kinds of iterators, I don't think you can enforce this "optimization", i.e. you can't generically check if two iterators point to the same object. If you're willing to forego input and output iterators, what you have should be fine. Otherwise, I'd stick with doing the copy in any case (I really don't think you have another option on this).

Comment: I guess I guessed the code had other problems, so I'm not surprised it's not OK... what I was asking was, is there a way to achieve what I'm asking? ("No" is an acceptable answer if correct...)

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper template function `equals` that automatically returns `false` if the iterators are different types. Either that or do a specialization or overload of your `copy` function itself.

If they're the same type then you can use your trick of comparing the pointers of the objects they resolve to, no casting required:

```
if (&*i != &*o)
    *o = *i;
```

If `*i` or `*o` doesn't return a reference, no problem - the copy will occur even if it didn't have to, but no harm will be done.

Comment: @Mehrdad, can you be more specific? Which part doesn't work, and why?

Comment: *"I can't use overloaded templated functions either, because the iterators might belong to different containers even though they have the same type."*

Comment: @Mehrdad, by dereferencing the iterators it no longer matters if they belong to the same container or not. Unless you think that elements of two containers might have the same pointer address, but I think that's impossible.

Comment: It matters because I don't think the standard allows you to compare iterators that belong to different containers.

Comment: @Mehrdad, you're not comparing iterators - you're comparing the objects that the iterators point to. Since it was your idea I'm surprised you didn't realize it.

Comment: Oh, I misread your last comment. I totally missed the part where you said *"by dereferencing the iterators"*. Well, the only reason I'm dereferencing the iterators is that that is my (flawed) **attempt** at achieving my goal. A correct solution, which is what my question is seeking, would not have its flaws, and would not *necessarily* have to dereference the iterators.